# Ampscript Personalization String for Subscriber CreatedDate in Email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am trying to check the created date for a subscriber upon sending an email to them.  I then want to use that value to do something different in the email if the Created Date is today to basically include a welcome section in a triggered send.

I have tried both

```
Set @CreatedDate = [CreatedDate]
Set @CreatedDate = [_CreatedDate]
```

but they both give the error: `The SET variable value expression is invalid.`

Is there a better way to do this or what the personalization string is for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a [Profile Attribute](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/profile_and_preference_attributes/) or [Data Extension](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_and_data_relationships/) column named `CreatedDate` for this to work.  There's no out-of-the-box `CreatedDate` [personalization string](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/).  The [AttributeValue()](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#AttributeValue) function will return an empty string if it doesn't exist.

```
%%[

var @CreatedDate
set @CreatedDate = AttributeValue("CreatedDate")

]%%
<br>CreatedDate: %%=v(@CreatedDate)=%%
```